# gdb hanging when attaching to java process

Tags: java, java-native-interface, gdb

I'm trying to debug a JNI code. For this purpose I'm following an idea about attaching gdb to the java process running my Java code.
The problem is when I do that gdb hangs at `pthread_join()` inside `libjli.so`, producing the following output.

```
0x7fff59850000
0x00007ffa9fbb8218 in pthread_join ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
```

And then I can't make my Java code attend to requests (it is a server).

Update: It is not inside `pthread_join()`, but after that, when I continue the execution and make a request to the server. It is using actually `libzmq.so` for communication. I don't know if gdb interferes the library somehow.

Comment: If you found a solution you should add it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out what was going on. Java uses SIGSEGV during garbage collection, which is intercepted by gdb causing an apparently crash. To solve this I added `handle SIGSEGV pass nostop` to my `~/.gdbinit` file.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can just use these two commands in gdb session before calling "run" command:

handle SIGSEGV nostop

handle SIGSEGV noprint

Comment: It is valid when you launch your process from gdb, but when you attach gdb to a running process those commands should be executed before gdb starts debugging.